# Multiply some amount with the total elapsed months since a specific month in google spreadsheet

Tags: math, google-sheets

I have something like this

```
 A             B               C
1 Cost    Start Date      Total to date
2 33      Aug 1st 2015        x
3 12      Aug 1st 2015        y
.  ..        ....                 ..

n           MAIN TOTAL       x+y+...
```

Here are the formulas I am interested in:

```
month = number of months between aug 1st 2015 and jan 1st 2016, witch is 5 - counting only the beginning of the month

x = A * month
```

What I'm not sure about is how to get the difference between today's month and the one specified in column `B`

Add on:

The date format is not set in stone, can be anything that is easy to calculate, i can store the readable format in a different column if needed

Comment: So in column C in your example, you'd want `33*5=165` and `12*5=60`, is that correct?

Comment: @tigeravatar yes please, but i need to find the `5` value to begin with

Comment: Did you **really** type in **1st** and made this a text representation of a date that Excel cannot recognize without removing the **st**? (or **nd** or **rd** or **th**)

Comment: @Jeeped i can change the date format, that's not an issue

Comment: Assuming column B contains actual dates (and  not text that looks like dates), use this formula in cell C2 and copy down: `=DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"m")*A2`

Comment: @tigeravatar that seems to work.. if u post your answer ill accept it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `tigeravatar`  my final formula

`=IF(DATEDIF(E14, TODAY(), "m") = 0, C14, DATEDIF(E14, TODAY(), "m") * C14)`

Comment: Could shorten that to: `=MAX(1,DATEDIF(E14,TODAY(),"m"))*C14`